# Container Thread Safety

Tags: c++11, concurrency, stl

I'm aware of Container Thread Safety topic listed there:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

But I want to know: can I use non-const member functions and const member functions concurrently without blocking (a mutex)?
More specific:

1. Can I use std::vector::push_back and std::vector::size concurrently?
2. Can I use std::set::insert and std::set::size concurrently?

This doesn't make a practical sense commonly, but I don't need an exact result of size which I'll use, I just need a **valid** result at the time when I call it.

P.S. My doubts are come from there: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/ where they say for std::set::insert that

> Concurrently accessing existing elements is safe

So maybe getting the size of containter is also safe.

Comment: "I don't need an exact result of size which I'll use, I just need a valid result at the time when I call it" - for that to work, size needs to be internally atomic, which it isn't. It's the same as with any ordinary variable that one thread writes and another thread reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread-safety rule of stl containers is that if more than one working thread is accessing a shared container, and at least one of them is `non-const`, then the threads should be synchronized. If you do not put any synchronizations, it will be undefined behavior.

if you take a look at the C++ reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) for `std::vector::size()`, it says:

> **Data Races**
>
> ***The container is accessed.*** No contained elements are accessed:
> concurrently accessing or modifying them is safe.

As mentioned, the `vector` container will be accessed during the call to `.size()` and this access does not allow you to call non-const methods at the same time on the `vector`. If you `push_back` an element into the vector when you get the size of the `vector` by calling `.size()`, then the behavior of your program will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think your statement is not absolutely right, because we may write to a 'vector', changing it element, and concurrently use 'size' for example. So I suppose either you mean "if more than one working thread is accessing a shared container, and at least one of them is **modify the mentioned container itself** (maybe as a side effect of writing to a container), the threads should be synchronized" or I don't understand your statement.

Comment: @cyrax **My statement in one phrase:** If two threads are accessing the same container, and one of them is writing into the container, then your threads should be synchronized. Otherwise the behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: You are writing the same, so it doesn't explain anything. In my example one thread is writing into the vector with `operator []` and other is calling const member function `size()` but they don't need to be synchronized as stated in Container Thread Safety topic. Do you agree with this or not?

Comment: @cyrax Sorry for my late reply. Yes, you are right. in that case according to the standard no synchronization is needed, because `operator[]` is considered as const here. I have updated my answer for that.